# What is the time complexity for these two programs?

Tags: java, recursion, stack, iteration, time-complexity

Can someone explain to me the time complexity for these three methods and help me understand why it is that time complexity. Both methods takes in a matrix and finds all its surrounding neighbours. The first method is done through recursion and the second one is done through iterations and stacks and third method is done through tail recursion.

Here is the first method:

```
public static int ExploreAndLabelColony(char[][] grid, int i, int j, char c) { 
        grid[i][j] = c;
        int count = 1;
            
        if ((i>0 && i<grid.length && j<grid[0].length) && (grid[i-1][j] == '1')) { //vertical top
            count += ExploreAndLabelColony(grid, i-1,j,c); 
            }
        if (i+1<grid.length && j<grid[0].length && grid[i+1][j] == '1') { //vertical bottom
            count +=ExploreAndLabelColony(grid, i+1,j,c); 
            }
        if (j>0 && i<grid.length && j<grid[0].length && grid[i][j-1] == '1') { //horizontal left
            count +=ExploreAndLabelColony(grid, i,j-1,c); 
            }
        if (i<grid.length && j+1<grid[0].length && grid[i][j+1] == '1') { //horizontal right
            count +=ExploreAndLabelColony(grid, i,j+1,c); 
            }
        if (i+1<grid.length && j+1<grid[0].length && grid[i+1][j+1] == '1') { //diagonal bottom right
            count +=ExploreAndLabelColony(grid, i+1,j+1,c);
            } 
        if (j>0 && i+1<grid.length && j<grid[0].length && grid[i+1][j-1] == '1') { //diagonal bottom left
            count +=ExploreAndLabelColony(grid, i+1,j-1,c);
            } 
        if (i>0 && i<grid.length && j+1<grid[0].length && grid[i-1][j+1] == '1') { //diagonal top right
            count += ExploreAndLabelColony(grid, i-1,j+1,c);
            } 
        if (i>0 && j>0 && i<grid.length && j<grid[0].length && grid[i-1][j-1] == '1') { //diagonal top left
            count +=ExploreAndLabelColony(grid, i-1,j-1,c);
            }
            
        return count;
    }
}
```

This is the second method:

```
public static int ExploreAndLabelColony(char[][] grid, int i, int j, char c) { 
        Stack<String> strStack = new Stack<>();
        strStack.push(i + "," + j);

        while (!strStack.empty()) {
            String x = strStack.pop();
            
            int row = Integer.parseInt(x.split(",")[0]);
            int col = Integer.parseInt(x.split(",")[1]);

            if(row<0 || col<0 || row>=grid.length || col>=grid[0].length || visited[row][col] || grid[row][col]!='1')
                continue;
            
            visited[row][col]=true;
            grid[row][col]=c;
            count++;
            strStack.push(row + "," + (col-1)); //left
            strStack.push(row + "," + (col+1)); //right
            strStack.push((row-1) + "," + col); //up
            strStack.push((row+1) + "," + col); //down
            strStack.push((row-1) + "," + (col-1)); //left & up
            strStack.push((row-1) + "," + (col+1)); //right & up
            strStack.push((row+1) + "," + (col-1)); //left & down
            strStack.push((row+1) + "," + (col+1)); //right & down  
        }    
    return count;
    }
```

This is the third method:

```
static int ExploreAndLabelColony(Point point, char[][] grid, char c, int count) {
    if (point == null) {
        return count; // no more work
    }
    int i = point.i;
    int j = point.j;
    point = point.next;
    if (i < 0 || j < 0 || i >= grid.length || j >= grid[0].length) {
        
    } else if (grid[i][j] != '1') {
        
    } else {
        grid[i][j] = c;  // label
        count++;
        point = new Point(i - 1, j - 1, point);
        point = new Point(i - 1, j, point);
        point = new Point(i - 1, j + 1, point);
        point = new Point(i, j - 1, point);
        point = new Point(i, j + 1, point);
        point = new Point(i + 1, j - 1, point);
        point = new Point(i + 1, j, point);
        point = new Point(i + 1, j + 1, point);
    }
    return ExploreAndLabelColony(point, grid, c, count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given n rows and m cols the time complexity should be O(mn) for both. Since you are passing grid by reference and not revisiting visited cells this is a depth first search. The second method is the same as the first method but replaces the call stack in the first method with your own stack.

Comment: what would be the time complexity of the third method?

Comment: “Finding surrounding neighbours” should be able to be done in O(n + m), because it’s a boundary operation.

Comment: not necessarily it depends on the shape of the boundary it could be like a spiral of which case it should be O(mn)

Comment: The time complexity of the third method should be O(mn).